# External stylesheet has no effect, although linked

Tags: html, css

That's my code:

```css
body { font-size: 4em; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hi</title>
  <link href="css/main.css"
        rel="styleshet">
</head>
<body>

Hello!

</body>
</html>
```

When I save the CSS file the `head` and the `link` tag in "elements" in the developer tools blinks purple but the CSS doesn't show up in "styles".

Same thing when I open index.html via explorer instead of live-server.

I've been staring at my monitor for a while and can't seem to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Must be a path issue.

Comment: mis-spelled stylesheet in rel="styleshet". should be rel="stylesheet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mis-spelled 'stylesheet'

```
...
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
```